# .htaccess issues

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a page that does two things:

When users click on this link:
http://www.example.com/whatever_200/index.html/?id=4 it is actually processed by
http://www.example.com/search/profile-condo.php?id=4

However, I also want to do the following for people in Brazil
www.example.com/br/whatever_200/index.html/?id=4
www.example.com/br/search/profile-condo.php?id=4

The following works great for the english version:

```
addhandler x-httpd-php5 .html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index.html$ /search/profile-condo.php?name=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,QSA]
```

But when I add

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/br/^(.*)/index.html$ /br/search/profile-condo.php?name=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,QSA]
```

It doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three problems with your rules.

First of all the rule order. The first rule will match anything ending with `/index.html`, and it will perform the redirect. It is (properly) flagged as the final rule (the `L` flag). Because of that, the second rule will never be executed. If you add add the `br` rule *before* the general rule, it will be tested first, and if it matches, the redirect will occur.

The second problem is the regular expression on your second rule. It contains a circumflex `^` halfway the expression. The circumflex means *start of string*, which obviously never occurs in the middle of the string. Removing the circumflex will fix that.

A third issue is that you're allowing characters before the `/br/` part of your url (by having `(.*)` in your expression. According to your description, you do not actually need this.

Summarizing:

```
addhandler x-httpd-php5 .html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/br/(.*)/index.html$ /br/search/profile-condo.php?name=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index.html$ /search/profile-condo.php?name=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,QSA]
```